# Why doesn't sudo need password when used in rc.local?

Tags: permissions, init

I have added

```
sh /home/victor/startupAP.sh
```

into `/etc/rc.local` and the `startupAP.sh` contains statement which need `sudo`:

```
$ cat startupAP.sh 
#!/bin/bash
sudo hostapd -B /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf 2>&1 >/home/victor/startupap.log
#sudo ifconfig wlan1 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0; sudo dhcpd wlan1 -pf /var/run/dhcp-server/dhcpd.pid; sudo bash -c "echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"; sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo ifconfig wlan1 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 2>&1 >>/home/victor/startupap.log
sudo dhcpd wlan1 -pf /var/run/dhcp-server/dhcpd.pid 2>&1 >>/home/victor/startupap.log
sudo bash -c "echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward" 2>&1 >>/home/victor/startupap.log
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE 2>&1 >>/home/victor/startupap.log
```

If I run this script in the terminal, it needs password,

```
$ sudo ./startupAP.sh
[sudo] password for victor:
```

but if I reboot, this script ran and worked as expected without password, why?

Comment: rc.local and all the system boot scripts are run as root.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Javier pointed out in comments, the scripts included in rc.local (and init.d) are run by `root` and then some of them drops privileges or change users, since running services with the root account is normally a security hole. If you want your script run by root even when calling them manually, you can use the [SETUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid):

```
sudo chown root /home/victor/startupAP.sh
sudo chmod +s /home/victor/startupAP.sh
```

But remember that the [setuid is ignored if you use a shebang](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2910/41104).